# The amount of information in a human brain

Tags: memory, working-memory

I have little background in the life sciences. I was told by a more informed person that the human brain can store an infinite amount of information. Doesn't this violate the laws of physics. If the amount of information is infinite, the entropy is also infinite. Wouldn't that violate Einstein's Theory of General Relativity. How much information can actually be stored in a human brain?

Comment: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9732/evidence-of-virtually-limitless-long-term-memory
http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/38/is-there-a-practical-limit-to-the-amount-of-knowledge-a-human-can-learn?rq=1

Comment: There is definitely not an infinite amount of information storage in the human brain, but we have no idea how to quantify it, so there is no good way to give a precise number.  see http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7855/why-do-scientists-say-brains-are-faster-than-computers/7858#7858 for discussion of a similar issue